# App for locating lost Android / iPhone devices by playing sound

Tags: android, chat, iphone-app, geo-location

I am looking for apps that will help me locate devices by playing a sound on them, overriding silence settings and similar.  Should be possible to use from web and  other devices.  Until now this is similar to what you can do with the web-based services from Google and Apple.

In addition, I would like that "friends" can give me access to "locate" their phones, that the channel can be used for other forms of communication, and that it can work locally (Bluetooth for example)

GPS location (like mention web sites) is of course nice, but it should be possible to restrict it.

Comment: Are you also interested in a solution for Android (or iOS) only, or must the solution a) run on both systems and b) support locating devices using both systems? -- Which "other forms of communication" do you mean exactly?

Comment: Android has an inbuilt feature. Just google "find my phone" and it will show you the current location of the phone. You can also make the phone ring to locate it. However to do so, the phone must not be in the 'Do not disturb' mode. As to giving friends access to locate their phones. This may not be seen as a 'feature' and as a threat to privacy. Therefore finding such apps might be difficult. I am not sure about iPhone.

Comment: @Aswin.  That is among "web based services" I mentioned.  Practically, if device is not nearby it is not inconvenient to open a web browser, so from a device GPS is not really important, and then privacy is not a difficult issue.

Comment: Avast! antivirus for android has this feature. It lets you remotely control your phone through SMS. You can sound an alarm, get GPS coordinates etc using SMS.

Comment: @unor. 1: Such a system is less interesting if it does not work works with other OSes of course. 2: You can imagine something like this integrated with a messaging system.

Comment: Apple does provide the second feature you're looking for (minus Bluetooth) via the Find My Friends app.